# Will command blocks still execute outside server render distance?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If I trigger a command block to summon a redstone block 5 chunks away,
 (which subsequently triggers several other command blocks) but the server render distance is set to 4 chunks, will the redstone block still be summoned and execute the other command blocks?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Nothing happens unless it's closer than the render distance or inside the spawn chunks. That's true in 99% of cases. Understanding the remaining one percent takes days of learning how the game works, but you usually don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the chunk in question is not loaded, then no. Commands like `/fill` and `/setblock` cannot affect unloaded chunks, and will fail with an error message.

Some options:

- Ensure that the chunks *will* be loaded, either by putting the command blocks in the spawn chunks or by building a chunk loader of some kind.
- Instead of using command blocks, use [functions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Function). I recommend this option, as functions have *much* better performance than command blocks and are easier to edit once you get started. Then, instead of placing a redstone block, you can just do `/function my_namespace:my_function` to run your commands.

Comment: I just looked into functions and it looks interesting, but primarily a lot of the command blocks I am using are for "vanilla-friendly" minigames. A lot require a previous action to be done first, and functions seem to do all instructions in one tick. 
As an example, I need to summon minecarts on a single point, spread them around that single point, then teleport them all to a specific y level (as spreadplayers teleports to top block). I'm not sure how this sequence would work using functions.

Comment: @JakeBristow yes, I guess that is like the biggest issue with functions. To provide timing, command blocks are still needed. Maybe a scoreboard-based clock that triggers functions via commandblocks located at spawn might do the trick.

Comment: I think I might just set up the "control room" of command blocks beneath the respective minigame, that way it's always guaranteed to be loaded. Thank you for your advice though!

Comment: @JakeBristow The first point in this answer about placing the command blocks in the spawn chunk is a good option.  The spawn chunks are always loaded if there is a player anywhere in the world. [Here is the wiki on spawn chunk](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn_chunk).  I recommend your control room be in these chunks.